# Why are parameters changing from one function to another in a class?

Tags: c++

I am creating a program called 3 card high card.  I am using deck, card, and hand classes.  The point of the program is to compare the players hand and the computers hand.  Whoever has the highest card wins.  If the highest two cards from each hand are equal, then the highest of the two middle cards wins, and if those are equal, the highest of the lowest cards.  If not, it's a tie.  My problem is where the compare function is comparing two hands.  I am getting erroneous results for my computer high card, and my computer middle card (c.hc and c.mc).  The results are correct in the sort function, but when they are pulled up in the compare function, it's not the right numbers.  However, the players hc, mc, and lc are correct as well as the computers lc.

Disregard the strange words in my compare function.  I have them there to figure out where the program is pulling the winner result in my if statements.  Also disregard how weird it looks that the results of hc, mc, and lc come after the word "winner is".  I only did this to see if my strange results were a result of the wrong numbers being in those parameters, and yes that was the problem.

```
Here is my main.cpp:
#include "3chc.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  srand(time(0));  
  Deck d;
  d.shuffle();

  cout << "computer: " << endl;
  Hand comp(3);
  comp.dealFrom(d);
  comp.reveal();
  comp.sort();

  cout << "player: " << endl;
  Hand player(3);
  player.dealFrom(d);
  player.reveal();
  player.sort();

  cout << "Winner is " << player.compare(comp, player) << endl;

  return 0;
}



--------------------------------------------

here is my 3chc.h:

//3chc.h Deck, Card, and Hand classes
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Card { 
  friend class Deck;
  private:
    int card_index; //card number 0 to 51
    Card(int index) { card_index = index; } //made this private so user can't say card at index 100..can use it because of friend class
  public:
    Card() { card_index = 52; }
    char suit() const;
    char value() const;
    std::string str() const;
    int getValue(std::string c);
};

class Deck {
  private:
    Card cards[52];
    int pos;
  public:
    Deck();
    Card deal() { return cards[pos++]; };
    void shuffle();
    int size() const { return 52 - pos; };
};

class Hand {
  friend class Deck;
  friend class Card;
  private:
    int handSize;
    int hc; //high card
    int mc; //middle card
    int lc; //low card
    Card myCards[];

  public:   
    Hand() { handSize = 1; };
    Hand(int n) { handSize = n; };
    void dealFrom(Deck& d);
    void reveal(); 
    //int getHandValues();   
    int total();
    void sort();
    std::string compare(Hand& c, Hand&p);
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Card& c);


----------------------------------------------

and here is my 3chc.cpp:


//3chc.cpp - Implementations of the Deck, Card, and Hand classes
#include "3chc.h"
#include <cstdlib>



char Card::suit() const {
  static char suits[] = { 'H', 'S', 'D', 'C' };
  //return card_index < 52 ? suits[card_index % 4] : 'X';
  return suits[card_index % 4];
}

char Card::value() const {
  static char values[] = 
    { '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' };
    //return card_index < 52 ? values[card_index / 4] : 'X';
    return values[card_index / 4];
}

std::string Card::str() const {
  std::string s;
  s += value();
  s += suit();
  return s;
}

Deck::Deck() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 52; i ++) {
//    Card c(i);
//    cards[i] = c;
    cards[i] = Card(i);
  }
  pos = 0;
}

void Deck::shuffle() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    int j = rand() % 52;
    Card tmp = cards[i];
    cards[i] = cards[j];
    cards[j] = tmp;
  }
  pos = 0;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Card& c) {
  out << c.str();
  return out;
}

int Card::getValue(std::string c) {
  char v = c[0];
  int val = v - '0';
  if (val > 9) {
    switch(v){
      case 'T':
        val = 10;
        break;
      case 'J':
        val = 11;
        break;
      case 'Q':
        val = 12;
        break;
      case 'K':
        val = 13;
        break;
      case 'A':
        val = 14;
    }
  }
  return val;

}
void Hand::dealFrom(Deck& d) {
  for(int i = 0; i < handSize; i++)
      myCards[i] = d.deal();
}

void Hand::reveal(){ 
  for (int i = 0; i < handSize; i++) 
    std::cout << myCards[i] << " " << std::endl;
}

int Hand::total() {
  int total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < handSize; i ++) {
    total += myCards[i].getValue(myCards[i].str());
  }
  return total;

}

void Hand::sort() {

  hc = myCards[0].getValue(myCards[0].str());
  mc = myCards[1].getValue(myCards[1].str());
  lc = myCards[2].getValue(myCards[2].str());
  int temp = 0;

  if (mc > hc) {
    temp = mc;
    mc = hc;
    hc = temp;
  };

  if (lc > hc) {
    temp = lc;
    lc = hc;
    hc = temp;
  };

  if (lc > mc) {
    temp = lc;
    lc = mc;
    mc = temp;
  };



  std::cout << "hc = " << hc << ", mc = " << mc << ", lc = " << lc << std::endl;


}

std::string Hand::compare(Hand& c, Hand&p) {
  std::string winner;



  while (c.hc == p.hc) {
    if (c.mc == p.mc) {
      if (c.lc == p.lc){
        winner = "tie";
      } else if (c.lc > p.lc) {
        winner = "cat";
      } else if (c.lc < p.lc) {
        winner = "pig";
      }
    } else if (c.mc > p.mc) {
      winner = "cell";
    } else if (c.mc < p.mc) {
      winner = "penguin";
    }
  }

  if (c.hc > p.hc) {
    winner = "computer";
  } 
  if (c.hc < p.hc) {
    winner = "player";
  }

  std::cout << "c hc = " << c.hc << " mc= " << c.mc << " lc= " << c.lc << std::endl;

  std::cout << "p hc = " << p.hc << " mc= " << p.mc << " lc= " << p.lc << std::endl;

  return winner;


}
```

I expect to have the c.hc and c.mc to be equal to what they are in the sort function.  I apologize if I didn't write this post correctly.  I have never posted here before.  This assignment is due tonight at midnight, and I could not find the answer to my question anywhere else on this site.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't see the issue at a very quick glance, but plopping this in an IDE with a debugger would probably let you see the issue very quickly by stepping through it.

Comment: `Card myCards[];` is a pointer, not an array. You don't allocate memory for it but dereference it. That's undefined behavior and probably the source of your problem. You could use std::vector to fix it.

Comment: I would do two things. First, I'd have the reveal function output the hc, mc, and lc to make sure that works. Secondly, I'd add debug statements to the compare method. That will probably help you find the problem in just a few minutes.

Comment: Try `std::vector<Card> myCards;` instead of `Card myCards[];`, `Hand() { handSize = 1; myCards.resize(1); }` and `Hand(int n) { handSize = n; myCards.resize(n); }`

Comment: Why is the hand size dynamic? The sort function only works with 3 cards. You could use a fixed hand size of 3.

Comment: If (c.hc == p.hc) is true, then compare() is going to go endless on the while loop.  Shouldn't that be an IF?

Agree with ArtHare, plug this into an IDE and debug to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: `Card myCards[];` is an error (array declarations in a class must have a dimension specified) . If you don't see compiler error messages then please adjust your compiler settings

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. Thomas Sablik, that worked.  Also, I planned on using this class for a blackjack program i am working on, so that's why the hand size is dynamic.  Also, boB, I originally had an IF statement, but when i was messing around to find out why it wasn't working, I changed it to a while, but you are right, I changed it back.  Thank you all so so much for your help.  I was always afraid to ask a question on here because i felt like I don't know enough, so I'm really grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`Card myCards[];` is a pointer, not an array. You don't allocate memory for it but dereference it. That's undefined behavior and probably the source of your problem.

Use `std::vector<Card> myCards;` instead of `Card myCards[];` and set the vector size in the constructors

```
Hand() { handSize = 1; myCards.resize(1); }
```

and

```
Hand(int n) { handSize = n; myCards.resize(n); }
```

The sort function only works with 3 cards. You could use a fixed hand size of 3 as a quick fix

```
Card myCards[3];
```

instead of the fix with `std::vector`.